# How does Gmail create this custom prompt dialog box?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, modal-dialog, gmail

Sometimes, when I try to close Gmail with multiple tabs open, I get a JS `prompt` function-style dialog box like the following:

[image: Gmail custom prompt dialog box example]

As far as I can tell though, it's impossible to customize the text used for buttons, etc. when using the JS `prompt` function.
Furthermore, this appears to be a true dialog box (as opposed to some JS-created modal) in that you cannot interact with the rest of the screen or pull up the element inspector, etc. until you act on the dialog box.

How does the Gmail team do this?
Do they have access to some undocumented functions/methods that the rest of us don't know about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload). It allows you to warn the user before they navigate away.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Note that many browsers ignore the return value and just show a default message, as it was commonly abused to show "WAIT! BUY OUR SPAMMY PRODUCT FOR 50% LESS!" on scam sites.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple and concise answer.